# Palm-pre app loading takes forever

Tags: webos, palm-pre, palm-pre2

HI, I am new to WebOS dev.

I finished writing the sample app of chapter 2 of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596155255), everything seems to be correct except when I start the app I get this:[image]

Is like my app is still loading but I can't really tell and it never ends. what does this mean and how can I debug this?  What could be causing this?

I have tried the original sample of the book and works fine, I have copied the source so I make sure there is no spelling misses but I still get this.
(Copied two assistants one model, modified one view and added the model path to sources.json with out success)

This app is super simple and should show some news (title and summary)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens often when there's a syntax error in the JavaScript code.  One way to find this is to use the palm-log tool in the SDK to dump out the output with your app id and see if anything is reported from V8.  You also can use the web-based Ares Log tool at http://ares.palm.com/AresLog/.

If there are no syntax errors, then this happens when you don't push an initial scene, so there's nothing telling the System Manager that it's ready to show the app's card.

Comment: Indeed there was a javascript related syntax error. I missed one comma in one JSON file ;) Thanks for the Ares tool link. I still don't know how to use it will do google it.